Ldap attribues for testing in Spring Boot with ApacheDS
I am trying to simulate a real Microsoft LDAP tree.
The application is working against a real LDAP, but using an inmemory LDAP server (ApacheDS) for testing in Spring Boot but it doesn't work. I can't replicate some attributes to make it work.
For example, my dn base is ou=users,dc=oficinas,dc=com:
dn: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=oficinas,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: user01
sn: user

I need attributes like memberOf: , distinguishedname: or objectCategory: , and ApacheDS doesn't recognize them when loading the .ldif file.
I'm trying to create the schema but apacheDS doens't allow me.
dn: ou=schema
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: schema

dn: m-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.32.1.1,ou=schema
m-collective: FALSE
m-singlevalue: TRUE
m-oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.32.1.1
m-obsolete: FALSE
m-description: Custom Attribute
m-nousermodification: FALSE
objectclass: metaAttributeType
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-syntax: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
m-usage: USER_APPLICATIONS
m-name: memberOf

dn: m-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.32.1,ou=schema
m-oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.32.1
m-obsolete: FALSE
m-supobjectclass: inetOrgPerson
m-description: -
objectclass: metaObjectClass
objectclass: metaTop
objectclass: top
m-name: customPerson
m-typeobjectclass: STRUCTURAL
m-may: memberOf
m-equality: objectIdentifierMatch

And runnig I see this error:
'm-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.32.1.1,ou=attributeTypes,ou=schema,dc=oficinas,dc=sepg,dc=minhac,dc=age' because it violates the provided schema:  The entry contains object class metaAttributeType which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains object class metaTop which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-oid which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-syntax which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-obsolete which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-collective which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-usage which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-name which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-nousermodification which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-singlevalue which is not defined in the schema.  The entry contains attribute m-description which is not defined in the schema.  The entry's RDN contains attribute m-oid which is not defined in the schema.]
    at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3291) ~[na:na]

I need those attributes to simulate the real operations (I try bitnami as a local server and I find the same problem). How can I add custom attributes in the schema? Can I do it using Spring Boot in the .ldif file?

Another way has been loading data as add or modify
dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.11.222.1 NAME 'memberOf'
  DESC 'Custom attribute memberOf'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE )

dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.11.222.2 NAME 'objectCategory'
  DESC 'Custom attribute objectCategory'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE )

dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: attributeTypes
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.11.222.3 NAME 'distinguishedname'
  DESC 'Custom attribute objectCategory'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15
  SINGLE-VALUE )

dn: cn=schema
changetype: modify
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.11.333.2 NAME 'customPerson'
  DESC 'Custom object person'
  SUP top
  STRUCTURAL
  MUST ( cn $ sn )
  MAY ( memberOf $ objectCategory $ distinguishedname ) )

dn: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=oficinas,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: customPerson
objectClass: top
cn: John Doe
sn: Doe
memberOf: cn=COFFEEIEC_GRP1,ou=group,dc=oficinas,dc=com
objectCategory: user
distinguishedname: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=oficinas,dc=com

And load the data with something like this
  LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection(ldapHost, ldapPort, bindDN, password);

  // Create an LDIF reader
    try (LDIFReader ldifReader = new LDIFReader(resourceLoader.getResource(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.ldiffile")).getInputStream())) {
      LDIFChangeRecord changeRecord;
      // Read each entry or change record in the LDIF file
      while ((changeRecord = ldifReader.readChangeRecord()) != null) {
          if (changeRecord instanceof LDIFAddChangeRecord) {
              LDIFAddChangeRecord addRecord = (LDIFAddChangeRecord) changeRecord;
              AddRequest addRequest = addRecord.toAddRequest();
              connection.add(addRequest);
          } else if (changeRecord instanceof LDIFModifyChangeRecord) {
              LDIFModifyChangeRecord modifyRecord = (LDIFModifyChangeRecord) changeRecord;
              ModifyRequest modifyRequest = modifyRecord.toModifyRequest();
              connection.modify(modifyRequest);
          }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }


By now is working creating before each test just the attribute and object getting a LDAPconnection, but I can't create those objects in the ldif file.
    @Autowired
    private LDAPConnection ldapConnection;

   @BeforeEach
    public void UserTest()  throws LDAPException{
        // Define the new attribut
        final AttributeTypeDefinition customAttributeType = new AttributeTypeDefinition(
                "2.25.128424792425578037463837247958458780603.1",
                "memberOf",
                null, // No description needed
                "caseIgnoreMatch",
                null, // No ordering matching rule needed
                null, // No substring matching rule needed
                "1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15",
                false, // Not single-valued
                null); // No extensions needed
        ldapConnection.modify("cn=schema",
           new Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "attributeTypes",
                customAttributeType.toString()));
        
        final AttributeTypeDefinition customAttributeType2 = new AttributeTypeDefinition(
                "2.25.128424792425578037463837547958458780603.1",
                "objectCategory",
                null, // No description needed
                "caseIgnoreMatch",
                null, // No ordering matching rule needed
                null, // No substring matching rule needed
                "1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15",
                false, // Not single-valued
                null); // No extensions needed
        ldapConnection.modify("cn=schema",
           new Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "attributeTypes",
                   customAttributeType2.toString()));
        
        final ObjectClassDefinition customObjectClass = new ObjectClassDefinition(
                 "custom-objectperson-oid",
                 "customPersonClass",
                 null, // No description needed
                 "inetOrgPerson",
                 ObjectClassType.STRUCTURAL,
                 new String[]{ "cn", "sn", "uid" }, // No attributes are required
                 new String[] { "memberOf","objectCategory" }, // customAttribute is optional
                 null); // No extensions needed
        ldapConnection.modify("cn=schema",
                 new Modification(ModificationType.ADD, "objectClasses",
                      customObjectClass.toString()));
        
        ldapConnection.add("cn=user01,ou=users,dc=oficinas,dc=com",
                 new Attribute("objectClass", "top", "customPersonClass"),
                 new Attribute("cn", "test"),
                 new Attribute("sn", "Duminni"),
                 new Attribute("uid", "test-user"),
                 new Attribute("memberOf", "OU"),
                 new Attribute("objectCategory", "user"));
    }

